# String replace regex match's capture group unless a different regex matches the same capture group in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, string-matching

This is about the simplest example I can come up with (and actually not a far cry from the actual use case) that I anticipate people might not tell me to simply change the regex itself, but here goes.

Say I have these lovely nonsensical input words: `sent seimk semek t͡ʃeno eint͡ɬi em t͡ʃeʃeimp t͡ɬent͡ɬien keinsen`

And I want to search replace all instances of `ei` OR `e` with `a` before `n` or `m`, which `(ei|e)(?:n|m)` matches, UNLESS

1. it is *directly* preceded (i.e. no negative lookbehinds, since they'll cause a false negative) by `t͡ɬ`, `t͡ʃ`, or `d͡ʒ`, so i.e. `(?:t͡ɬ|t͡ʃ|d͡ʒ)(ei|e)`, or
2. if the n/m is *directly* succeeded (i.e. no negative lookaheads, for the same reason) by `p`, `t`, or `k`, i.e. if `(ei|e)(?:n|m)(?:p|t|k)` matches

The desired output is therefore `sent seimk samek t͡ʃeno ant͡ɬi am t͡ʃeʃeimp t͡ɬent͡ɬian kansan`.

So if the "find and replace" function in JS is `String.replace(RegExp pattern, String replacement)`, then then you would have to compress all 3 regexes into 1 for the first argument, which 1) I don't think is possible? It would require negative non-capturing groups which... aren't a thing, right? and 2) in the actual use case, the regex patterns are generated by a text parser, not by hand, and I don't have enough faith in my ability to write a parser smart enough to optimize.

The other way I thought about doing this was to simply cache all the matches to the first regex in a dictionary, and then remove everything that should be ruled out by the other two, but when you look at the output:

```js
let sEnv = "(ei|e)(?:n|m)";
let reEnv = new RegExp(sEnv, "g");  

let sExc1 = "(?:t͡ɬ|t͡ʃ|d͡ʒ)(ei|e)";
let reExc1 = new RegExp(sExc1, "g");

let sExc2 = "(ei|e)(?:n|m)(?:p|t|k)";
let reExc2 = new RegExp(sExc2, "g");

let sWords = "sent seimk semek t͡ʃeno eint͡ɬi em t͡ʃeʃeimp t͡ɬent͡ɬien keinsen";
let tWords = sWords.split(" ");
for (i = 0; i < tWords.length; i++){
    let sCurrentWord = tWords[i];
    let result;
    let tMatches = {}
    // first cache all the matches (ignoring the exceptions)
    while (result = reEnv.exec(sCurrentWord)) {
    tMatches[result.index] = result[0].length;
    }
    // then remove the exceptions
    while (result = reExc1.exec(sCurrentWord)) {
    delete tMatches[result.index];
    }
    while (result = reExc2.exec(sCurrentWord)) {
    delete tMatches[result.index];
    }
    // then apply all remaining matches
    let sOutput = sCurrentWord;
    for (var index in tMatches){
    
        console.log(sCurrentWord+": starting at "+index+", "+tMatches[index]+" chars long");
    }

}
```

It's... a bit confused. Not only is it apparently capturing the `n` despite being in a non-capturing group (result length printed keeps being 2 when the thing I want to capture is only 1 char long), but it also filtered out `eint͡ɬi` but kept `t͡ʃeno` as matches, which is the opposite of what it's supposed to do - and as the length of the input list grows this method must get *quite* slow.

How else can I go about this find-and-replace?

Comment: Can't you make plesae a more simple example with let's say English fruit names combined with special characters like capital letters which are more recognisable.

Comment: Any feedback on my solution? It seems to do what you need.

Comment: Please clarify what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

You actually have more hidden requirement here, namely the `p`, `t`, `k` cannot be followed with a diacritic mark.

Your main mistake is that you think that lookarounds cannot be used to match locations *immediately* preceded/followed with some pattern. In fact, **lookarounds DO and ALWAYS DO match locations that are *immediately* preceded/followed with some patterns**.

In your case, you can use (assuming you are using the ECMAScript 2018 compliant `RegExp`):

```js
text = text.replace(/(?<!t͡ɬ|t͡ʃ|d͡ʒ)(ei?)(?=[nm](?![ptk](?!\p{M})))/gu, 'a')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/olefvJ/3). Details:

- `(?<!t͡ɬ|t͡ʃ|d͡ʒ)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is `t͡ɬ`, `t͡ʃ` or `d͡ʒ` *immediately* to the left of the current location
- `(ei?)` - `ei` or `e`
- `(?=[nm](?![ptk](?!\p{M})))` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is *immediately* followed with `n` or `m` that are not *immediately* followed with `p`, `t` nor `k` that are not immediately followed with any diacrtic mark (`\p{M}`).

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const regex = /(?<!t͡ɬ|t͡ʃ|d͡ʒ)(ei?)(?=[nm](?![ptk](?!\p{M})))/gu;
const text = 'sent seimk semek t͡ʃeno eint͡ɬi em t͡ʃeʃeimp t͡ɬent͡ɬien keinsen';
console.log(text.replace(regex, 'a'));
```